# How to use same rejected in same slice in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have this extrareducers:

```
extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(getTopicsByDcResponsable.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      if(action.payload.status === 200){        
        state.error = '';
        state.userTopics.responsableTopics.push(...action.payload.data); 
      } else {
        state.error = action.payload.data;

      }    
    });

    builder.addCase(getTopicsByDcResponsable.rejected, (state, action) => {     
      state.error = action.payload;
    });
         
    builder.addCase(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit.fulfilled, (state, action) => {     
        if(action.payload.status === 200){
          state.error = '';
          state.userTopics.editorTopics.push(...action.payload.data);  
        } else {
          state.error = action.payload.data;
        }   
      });

    builder.addCase(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit.rejected, (state, action) => {     
      state.error = action.payload;
    });
  },
```

All the rejected recieve the same message in case that the backend has an error 'Network Error'.

In redux you can use the same reducer for all the errors.
How can i use the same rejected in redux Toolkit if all recieve the same error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define a single error handler function and pass it to the `builder.addMatcher` method.

Something like this should prevent redundancy.

```
const handleRejected = (state, action) => {
  state.error = action.error.message === "Network Error" ? "Network Error" : "Unexpected Error";
};

extraReducers: builder => {
  builder
    .addCase(getTopicsByDcResponsable.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload.status === 200) {
        state.error = '';
        state.userTopics.responsableTopics.push(...action.payload.data); 
      } else {
        state.error = action.payload.data;
      }    
    })
    .addMatcher(
      action => action.type.endsWith("/rejected"),
      handleRejected
    )
    .addCase(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      if (action.payload.status === 200) {
        state.error = '';
        state.userTopics.editorTopics.push(...action.payload.data);  
      } else {
        state.error = action.payload.data;
      }   
    })
    .addMatcher(
      action => action.type.endsWith("/rejected"),
      handleRejected
    );
},
```

Edit: You can try this if you want to remove additional `.addMatcher`

```
const isRejected = action => action.type.endsWith("/rejected");

builder
  .addCase(getTopicsByDcResponsable.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    // Handle fulfilled action for getTopicsByDcResponsable
  })
  .addCase(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    // Handle fulfilled action for getTopicsbyDcentroEdit
  })
  .addMatcher(isRejected, (state, action) => {
    // Handle all rejected actions
    state.error = action.error.message === "Network Error" ? "Network Error" : "Unexpected Error";
  });
```

Comment: would be possible insert .addMatcher() just once? for all the rejecteds?

Comment: @ddaudiosolutions I have updated the answer with an additional piece of code you could use as reference. Could you accept the answer and mark the question as solved? The previous example already solved it, this is just extra